# My horizontal barplot cuts off some text when i save the image. How to I make bars shorter and text longer?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm new to R so forgive my ignorance. So, I created a basic horizontal barplot using `barplot(`). My text on the y-axis mostly disappears.

[image][image]

Is there a way to lengthen and display the text? This is my code:

```
barplot(mydata$`Sum Impact Risk`~mydata$`Ecosystem Services`,
        x = "Impact Risk", 
        y = "",col=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Pastel1"))(23), 
        cex.axis=1, 
        cex.lab=1.4, 
        cex=0.6,
        horiz = 1,
        las=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try increase the margin of the plot area, default is `mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1)` for bottom, left, top, right. If you increase the left margin, it should be ok, for example :

```
par(mar=c(5.1, 8, 4.1, 2.1))
```

Just increase the second number until it is satisfying and after you can plot again